# Randomly choose 15 files and copy them to output folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Must work on XP/Vista/7. Can use batch, VBS, or whatever else anyone with the mentioned O/Ses can run (except PE).

Need to choose 15 random files, and also similarly named folders (which are in a different location), and copy them to their own folder at the same time.

I've scoured google and websites like robvanderwoude.com, and found a few close examples, but I'm too inexperienced to adapt the examples to what I need without going cross-eyed. I'd appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction (most efficient/easiest method to use), or some example possibly with a brief explanation I can also learn from.

Layout description:

```
30 files:
%~dp0\mod\store\XMLs -> %~dp0\mod\0.1.2\map\data  
map01_aaa.xml  
map02_bbb.xml  
map03_ccc.xml  
...  
map60_zzz.xml

30 folders:
%~dp0\mod\store\models -> %~dp0\mod\0.1.2\sky\stuff  
01_aaa_map  
02_bbb_map  
03_ccc_map  
...  
60_zzz_map
```

The code below is what I'm trying to adopt this to, but it only chooses 15 files/folders in order. Tried using the %random% environment var in an equation for SrcMax, but that just chooses a random amount of files and always starts with the first file.
(old code)

```
rem @ECHO OFF
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SET SrcCount=0
SET SrcMax=15

  FOR %%F IN (%~dp0\mod\store\XMLs\*.*) DO IF !SrcCount! LSS %SrcMax% (
  SET /A SrcCount += 1
  ECHO !SrcCount! COPY %%F %~dp0\mod\0.1.2\map\data\
  COPY %%F %~dp0\mod\0.1.2\map\data\
  SET FNAME=%%~nF
  ECHO XCOPY /s "%~dp0\mod\store\Models\!FNAME:~3!_map"  "%~dp0\mod\0.1.2\sky\stuff\!FNAME:~3!_map\"
  XCOPY /s "%~dp0\mod\store\Models\!FNAME:~3!_map"  "%~dp0\mod\0.1.2\sky\stuff\!FNAME:~3!_map\"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set XMLs_src=.\mod\store\XMLs
set XMLs_dest=.\mod\0.1.2\map\data
set maps_src=.\mod\store\models
set maps_dest=.\mod\0.1.2\sky\stuff

rmdir /q /s "%XMLs_dest%" 2>NUL
rmdir /q /s "%maps_dest%" 2>NUL
mkdir "%XMLs_dest%"
mkdir "%maps_dest%"

for /L %%X in (1,1,15) do (
    call :rnd rn
    call :xml !rn!
    call :map !rn!
)
copy "%XMLs_dest%\*.*" "%XMLs_src%" >NUL
echo d | xcopy /q /f /e /y "%maps_dest%\*" "%maps_src%" >NUL
echo Done.
goto :EOF

:rnd
set c=0
for /d %%I in (%maps_src%\*) do set /a c+=1 >NUL
set /a %1=%RANDOM% * %c% / 32768 + 1 >NUL
goto :EOF

:xml
set c=0
for /f %%I in ('dir /b /o:n "%XMLs_src%"') do (
    set /a c+=1 >NUL
    if !c!==%1 (
        echo %XMLs_src%\%%I -^> %XMLs_dest%\%%I
        move "%XMLs_src%\%%I" "%XMLs_dest%" >NUL
        goto :EOF
    )
)
goto :EOF

:map
set c=0
for /f %%I in ('dir /b /o:n "%maps_src%"') do (
    set /a c+=1 >NUL
    if !c!==%1 (
        echo %maps_src%\%%I -^> %maps_dest%\%%I
        echo d | xcopy /q /f /e /y "%maps_src%\%%I" "%maps_dest%\%%I" >NUL
        rmdir /q /s "%maps_src%\%%I"
        goto :EOF
    )
)
goto :EOF
```

It basically moves to prevent duplication, then copies from destination back to source to restore what was moved away.

Comment: Can't get it to work. Tried for 3 hours now but it won't move/copy files, what am I doing wrong? Output: http://pastebin.com/vkm1NnGM | Tried again with %c%==%%1 instead, Output: http://pastebin.com/mp8CmRmf | Tried again with %~dp0 instead of . for path vars, Output: http://pastebin.com/TFVtXT8x

Comment: XMLs folder is missing from the store now, and it's copying over all 30 files/folders, not 15. I'll mess around with it see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Sometimes doesn't work either, have to run it several times for it to start copying/moving stuff.

Comment: I don't think I can figure this out. I got it to move and copy back the XML files (not the folder), but it's not random, only the first 15 XMLs are moved/copied. The folders in the model folder are all moved/copied, not 15. Any idea what's going on? All I changed was removing the \\* and adding \\*.* to %XMLs_src% for the :xml label.

Comment: I broke down and created some test files similar to what you described in your original post.  I fixed some issues and this now works for me, pulling 15 random maps and matching XMLs.

Comment: If you're curious, the problems I addressed were that xcopy prompts for "does XXX specify a file or directory name" and halts execution of the script (which `echo d | xcopy etc` fixes); and that the for loops didn't always seem to encounter files / directories in alphabetical order when expected.  If you'd like me to put some verbose comments in my code to explain what stuff does, I can if you wish?

Comment: Works perfect now, thanks a bunch. I ended up getting the original to choose 15 randoms, but wouldn't move the others at all. If you want to add some comments I'd appreciate it, so would others who may read this in the future, I'm sure. I'll figure the changes out with some more reading though, like why the -^, echos, and bare file names saved the day.

Comment: @ronald - I heavily commented the script and pasted it at http://pastebin.com/atr8nsU7 .  Enjoy!